# Listing data slowly in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, indexing

I am using code-igniter version 3.1.6 and xampp control panel v3.2.2 ,listing customer details by table wise and join two table 'tbl_customer' and 'tbl_additional_details' tbl_customer"cus_id" is set a index and primary key

My Query like

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_additional_details');
$this->db->join('tbl_customer','tbl_additional_details.customer_id = tbl_customer.cus_id ');
$this->db->where('tbl_additional_details.branch_id',$_SESSION['branchs']);
 $this->db->order_by('tbl_additional_details.customer_id',"desc");
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
```

why the listing show very slowly any way to improve the result time?

Comment: you can add selected field in select statement inside `$this->db->select('*');`

Comment: @NikuNjRathod i wand all fields

Comment: If it's not too late maybe you can change that to "branches" from the misspelled "branchs". When things like that get fossilized in your code, like the venerable HTTP "referer", it can be a bit awkward.

Comment: how many results it produces? and if few then it might be related to database connection or how you display it on view

Comment: @Riyenz :1000 plus data, and show by datatable

Comment: Can you show us the resulting `SELECT`, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It may simply need a composite index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries optimisation is a complex topic... you could do with running the SQL in MySQL directly and doing some profiling there, but start with:

1. Make sure you create an index on any field that you might select or join on.
2. Run "optimize" on all your tables... you can do that from phpmyadmin. Do this AFTER creating your indexes.
3. Consider "denormalization", i.e. merge the tables or duplicate certain fields. For example if you are joining 2 tables for the sake of getting ONE extra field, you might want to copy that extra field over to the first table and eliminate the join altogether. This produces drastic increases in speed on large tables. Look at example here: http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i257/f99/Lecture9_257/sld018.htm

All the best!